# Permission denied to script on script created dir

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04

The script `yii/framework/utils/CFileHelper.php` is creating a dir dynamically but each time it tries to write to this dir, it gets the error:

```
copy(/var/www/devsite/wpyii/assets/6ab3d6ea/JsTrans.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Stack trace for line in question:

```
/var/www/devsite/yii/framework/utils/CFileHelper.php(130): copy("/var/www/devsite/wpyii/protected/extensions/JsTrans/JsTrans.js", "/var/www/devsite/wpyii/assets/6ab3d6ea/JsTrans.js")
```

I've tried deleting the dir, but each time the script recreates it, it can't write these generated files to it.

Also tried `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/devsite/wpyii/assets` but no good.

The dir `/var/www/devsite/wpyii/assets/6ab3d6ea1` and all other dirs under `/var/www` are owned by by `vagrant` (this is an Ubuntu vagrant box).

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant  68 Nov 12 02:38 6ab3d6ea/
```

If I `ls -l /var/www/devsite/wpyii/protected/extensions/JsTrans` for the source dir, I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 3644 Oct 27 22:52 JsTrans.js*
```

No idea what changed since I last booted this box up. I have not changed any of the vagrant configs.

How do I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: So which user `id` is this process running under?

Comment: The output from PHP in that script for `get_current_user()` is "vagrant" and for `getmyuid()` it's "1000".

Comment: Probably more a [tag:php] problem than an [tag:ubuntu] problem.  We can only assume that your PHP code does something ... weird.

Comment: @tripleee couldn't be more weird than all the other Yii developers that use the `CFileHelper` class. File is totally unmodified from default and no changes to any of the framework files since last boot according to git.

Comment: Have you got rx permissions to _/var_, _/var/www_, _/var/www/devsite_ and _/var/www/devsite/wpyii_ for user vagrant?

Comment: @RafałToboła all of the above owned by `vagrant`, except `/var` is owned by `root`.